# 100% accuracy with decision tree classifier using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm using Decision tree classifier from sklearn,  but I'm getting 100% percent score and I don't know what is wrong. I have tested svm and knn and both give 60% to 80% accuracy and seem ok. Here is my code:

```
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    maxScore = 0
    index = 0
    Depths = [1, 5, 10, 20, 40]
    for i,d in enumerate(Depths):
        clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=d)
        score = cross_val_score(clf1, X_train, Y_train, cv=10).mean()     
        index = i if(score > maxScore) else index
        maxScore = max(score, maxScore)
        print('The cross val score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=' + str(d) + ') is ' + 
        str(score))

    d = Depths[index]
    print()
    print("So the best value for max_depth parameter is " + str(d))
    print()

    # Classifying
    clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=d)
    clf1.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    preds = clf1.predict(X_valid)
    print(" The accuracy obtained using Decision tree classifier is {0:.8f}%".format(100* 
    (clf1.score(X_valid, Y_valid))))
```

and here is the output:
The cross val score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=1) is 1.0

The cross value score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=5) is 0.9996212121212121

The cross val score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=10) is 1.0

The cross val score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=20) is 1.0

The cross val score for Decision Tree classifier (max_depth=40) is 0.9996212121212121

So the best value for the max_depth parameter is 1

The accuracy obtained using Decision tree classifier is 100.00000000%

Comment: If this helps, I'll post this as an answer)

Comment: Harut Hunanyan
Well, that was exactly the case. Thanks a lot. What Should I do to make the results better?

Comment: Well, it depends on your problem. First of all can you say why you consider it as a problem? I'm not sure, but I guess it's because you think that your model is overfitted. And as the problem mostly depend on data, all i can recomend is using another model, with different approach.

Comment: All I told is now added as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There actually was a feature in my matrix that fully described the target values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's an obvious conclusion: your labels have high correlation with some of the features, or at least with one of them. Maybe your data isn't very good.

Anyway, you can check how a single feature split of your decision tree model affects on model prediction.

Use `model.feature_importances_` property to see how 'important' a feature is for the model prediction.

Check the documentation [Decision Tree Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

If you still consider your model prediction isn't good enough, I recommend you to change your model, use model with different approach. At least if you have to work with decision trees, you can try [Random Forest Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

It is an [ensemble model](https://courses.analyticsvidhya.com/courses/ensemble-learning-and-ensemble-learning-techniques?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=comprehensive-guide-for-ensemble-models).The basic idea of ensemble learning is that the final model prediction is based on multiple weaker model predictions, [weak learners](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-formal-definition-of-%E2%80%9Cweak-learner%E2%80%9D-and-an-intuitive-explanation-of-it). Check main approaches of making an [ensemble models](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/01/ensemble-learning-5-main-approaches.html).

In the case of Random Forest Classifier, weak learner models are Decision Trees with small depth. And Decision Trees are making predictions using only a few number of features, and every time features are chosen randomly.Number of chosen features is a hyper-parameter, so it needs to be tuned.

Check the links and other tutorials for more information.